# javascript function if else. Pico Fermi Bagel game

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, if-statement

Instead of "You win" I'm getting " Pico Pico Pico?? 
why the response is returning pico pico pico instead of You win.. since is the last statement  is you win..........
This are the rules of the game.......
The computer generates a three digit number where each digit must be unique. You are provided infinite turns to guess the number. The computer can give the following hints in response to each guess:

```
           Pico: One digit is correct but in the wrong place
            Fermi: One digit is correct and in the right place
            Bagels: No digits are correct

// global V
var compChoice1, compChoice2, compChoice3;
var number1, number2, number3;
var response;
//functions to create random numbers
function getRandomNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}

function startGame(){
    do{
        compChoice1 = getRandomNum();
        compChoice2 = getRandomNum();
        compChoice3 = getRandomNum();
    }
    while (compChoice1 == compChoice2 || compChoice1 == compChoice3 || compChoice2 == compChoice3);
}


//here we'll get the usr Numnber
function userNum(){
  number1 = document.getElementById('guessNum1').value;
  number2 = document.getElementById('guessNum2').value;
  number3 = document.getElementById('guessNum3').value;
    console.log(number1,number2,number3);
}

    // Compare Usr numbers vs computer ramdom nums
    function compareUsrvsCom(){

        var response = "";


        if (number1 == compChoice1) response += "pico  ";
        else if (number1 == compChoice2 || number1 == compChoice3) response += "fermi  ";


        if (number2 == compChoice2) response += "pico  ";
        else if (number2 == compChoice1 || number2 == compChoice3) response += "fermi  ";


        if (number3 == compChoice3) response += "pico  ";
        else if (number3 == compChoice1 || number3 == compChoice2) response += "fermi  ";


        if (number1 === compChoice1 && number2 === compChoice2 && number3 === compChoice3) response += "You win";
        else if (response == "" ) return ("beagls   ")


        return response;
        // return response;
    }
       //Start game Btn
document.getElementById('startGame').addEventListener('click', function() {
       startGame();
       console.log(compChoice1,compChoice2, compChoice3);
   });

   document.getElementById("guessButn").addEventListener("click", function() {
     userNum();
     compareUsrvsCom();
     console.log(compareUsrvsCom());
       document.getElementById("demoBagel").innerHTML = compareUsrvsCom();
     });
```

Comment: what is your response,number1,compChoice and other variables

Comment: Use console.log to log the values of everything.

Comment: Its likely the `==` vs `===` but can hard to say without seeing how you get input

Comment: You're appending `"You win"` to `response`... maybe you want to replace `response` with it or just return it directly?

Comment: Could we have the full source? Also, the game is Pico Fermi Bagel ;)

Comment: just posted the full source :)

Comment: Please also mention values you entered for guessNum1 & guessNum2 & guessNum3

Comment: that's my Id on my HTML
<input type="number" min="0" max="9" class="input-sm" maxlength="1" id="guessNum1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `==` is not the same as `===`

The problem is that you have two types that you are trying to compare. With

```
number1 = document.getElementById('guessNum1').value;
```

you are getting a `string` you can see this by with

```
console.log(typeof number1);
```

With the `compChoice1` you are getting an `number`. You can see that with

```
console.log(typeof Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
```

You are mixing the two comparison operators `==` and `===`. The `==` operator is less strict.

#### `5 == "5"` is true, however `5 === "5"` is false.

This is why your "you win" if statement is failing.  You should almost always use the `===` operator and make sure you are comparing the same types.

So we want to parse the value of `guessNum1` to be an integer, you can do that with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

### Use `parseInt` to convert user input to `number` type

```
function userNum(){
   number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('guessNum1').value);
   number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('guessNum2').value);
   number3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('guessNum3').value);
   console.log(number1,number2,number3, typeof number1);
}
```

This will give you all `number` types.

#### Prefer `===` over `==`

So convert the comparison operators in `compareUsrvsCom`

```
function compareUsrvsCom(){

   var response = "";

   if (number1 === compChoice1) response += "pico  ";
   else if (number1 === compChoice2 || number1 === compChoice3) response += "fermi  ";

   if (number2 === compChoice2) response += "pico  ";
   else if (number2 === compChoice1 || number2 === compChoice3) response += "fermi  ";

   if (number3 === compChoice3) response += "pico  ";
   else if (number3 === compChoice1 || number3 === compChoice2) response += "fermi  ";

   if (number1 === compChoice1 && number2 === compChoice2 && number3 === compChoice3) response += "You win";
   else if (response == "" ) return ("beagls   ")

   return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! now I understand better !!